# How do I align an inner div in an outer div properly by CSS

Tags: css, html

I have a footer div which is a simple div it has a fixed height and with (and it has a background picture which is why this is necessary).

I want it to contain an other smaller div, but all the text, and tiny icons in it should be aligned to the middle of the footer div.
Also I want the smaller div to be located in the bottom of the footer div.

Like when you select horizontal: center, vertical: bottom in cell alignment in excel.

What would be the ideal solution for this? I'm not good with css.
Javascript is out of the question.

Comment: Does (or can) the smaller div have a fixed height as well ?

Comment: @LapinLove: If necessary yes.
But I'll possibly have to modify it later.                 

@kjy112:
<div id="footer">
 text and icons (these could be centered too)
 <div id="footersfooter">
  text and icons centered and on the bottom of the footer div
 </div>
</div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what exactly is in the footer, but here is one solution assuming it's simple text:

```
<style>
#footer {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
}

#footer .inner {
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>

<div id="footer">
    <div class="inner">some text</div>
</div>
```

With a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MB9q4/)

Also depends what the image is, you might be able to do away with the inner `div` completely and just use some `padding-top` to push the content down.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure but I think you have to use "relative" instead of "absolute"

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is simple.  I think you already have this part:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer_content">
        footer stuff goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS isn't too complicated either.  You already have CSS for #footer.  I'm setting the #footer_content width & height to 400px and 60px - you'll have to choose how big to make it based on your needs.

```
#footer_content {
    width: 400px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This much will center the #footer_content div.  To take it a step further, lets position the div with a top margin, too:

```
#footer_content {
    width: 400px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 25px auto;
}
```

This will center the #footer_content div and push it down 25px.  If you're sure of the exact dimensions of the div, that's great and you can work with that.  If you want to be a little more flexible...

```
#footer_content {
    width: 400px;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50px;
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
}
```

The CSS for #footer is in addition to any other CSS you may have.  The position could be set to absolute or fixed, if you already have that set up - it just can't be set to static.

This will position the #footer_content relative to it's containing element, #footer.  In this case I have placed it 10px up from the bottom of #footer and 50px from the left edge.  You can also use the `top` and `right` attributes to position the div relative to those sides.

To learn more about the CSS Box Model, check this out: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

Comment: `Position: relative` does not position the element with a position relative to its containing element. It will rather be positioned relative to its "normal" position.

To position the element with a a position relative to its containing element you need to set `position: relative` for the containing element and `position: absolute` to your element (see roryf's answer)

Comment: I don't want to split hairs here, but the normal position is already dictated by the containing element.  The child element can be relatively or absolutely positioned vs. the parent element.  The parent element doesn't have to have a particular position type.  see this Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/LYjvJ/

Comment: Looks fine with top and left positioning... but try `bottom: 10px` : http://jsfiddle.net/LYjvJ/1/

To learn more about CSS positioning, see http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: I'm thinking of the wrong thing.  You're right - if you want to position the inner div according to the boundaries of the outer, position needs to be absolute and the container needs to be non-static. I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if your HTML is

```
<div id="footer">
    text and <img src="icons.gif" /> (these could be centered too)
        <div id="footersfooter">
            text and <img src="another icons.gif" /> centered and on the bottom of the footer div
        </div>
</div>
```

Try using *(modified code from roryf's to have #footer content centered)*

```
#footer {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative; /* important to position .inner relatively to #footer */
    text-align: center;
    width: 800px;
}

#footer .inner {
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```